# Import Action in New Oozie Editor

Tags: cloudera, oozie, hue

I am trying to understand how to import an action (like a job I created in the job designer) with the new Oozie editor that there is. Here is the best documentation I can find to describe the basics of the changes:

http://gethue.com/new-apache-oozie-workflow-coordinator-bundle-editors/

My question is... Where is this button (highlighted) in the new editor:

[image: Old Editor]

I want to be able to import a job that I created in the job designer like in the old editor. There is a "sub workflow button", but that will only allow me to import workflows and not jobs. The import action would let me pick from all jobs and workflows. I can't find this in the new editor (SS in link). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Cloudera forum admin (http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Web-UI-Hue-Beeswax/Import-Action-in-New-Oozie-Editor/m-p/44098#M1648):

Currently there is no way to import jobs from the Job Designer in the
Workflow Editor.

This will be back in Hue 4 though.